# How to turn off HTML5 validation rules in a Razor view that returns XML?

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, html, razor

In my MVC4 app I have a Razor view which returns some XML.

In Visual Studio, all of the XML tags are highlighted as not being valid HTML5 markup.

Ok, I could live with that - except the HTML5 validation is also not letting me use the `<source>` element in my XML as I would like.

It actually causes my view to throw an error, presumably because my use of the `<source>` element is not valid in HTML5.

How can I turn off the HTML5 validation in Razor, or tell it that my view is producing XML, not HTML?

Answer (score 2):

I just came up with a workaround. If I output the `<source>` tag using HTML.Raw() it seems OK:

```
<some_markup>
@Html.Raw("<source>")@Model.DeviceId@Html.Raw("</source>")
</some_markup>
```

Kind of lame, but it works. I'd still like to know how to make Razor behave with XML though.